# Oracle view - permissions needed on base tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Say I create an Oracle view MyView which uses MyTableA.

create view MyView as select ColumnA from MyTable;

Now, I grant you select access to MyView.  Do you also need select access on MyTableA in order to be able to select from MyView?

A colleague says 'yes' but this page;

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datadict.htm

states;

> User-Accessible Views
>   The views that summarize and display the information stored in the base tables of the >data dictionary. These views decode the base table data into useful information, such as >user or table names, using joins and WHERE clauses to simplify the information. Most **users are given access to the views rather than the base tables.**

Comment: Not required. Permission on the view is enough

Comment: The grantee of the select on the view does not need to have been granted select on the base tables, but the grantor of the select on the view needs to have the grant option on the base tables.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't. One of the purposes of views is to restrict access to the underlying data, which would be impossible if you had to give permissions for the actual table(s) as well.

[Read more in the concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16508/schemaob.htm#i20690).

Answer (score 0):

For simple selection you don't need any permission on base table. However, in case your view calls custom functions or object types, then your user must have `EXECUTE` privilege also for such functions, resp. object types.